# Loading vxworks 5.5.1 image on my atom board just shows 1.6+++++++ on the console

Tags: vxworks

I am working on vxworks 5.5.1 and Tornado 2.2.1 porting a BSP for an Intel atom board.

I have set the options (memory, console (serial) and other options) and produced a bootrom and vxworks image.

my development host is a 32-bit XP and I created a boot floppy image using mkboot a: bootrom

Then I used HDD raw copy to copy the image to a USB.

When I boot the atom board with the USB, all I see is the display "1.6+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++".

Since I compiled serial code into the bootrom (and there is a Rs-232 on the board), I was expecting to see some output on the Tornado COM1 console running in my environment.

It does not look like the bootrom is talking to serial port on the board at all.

Does anyone have any clues on where to look?
Thanks,
RK

Comment: Are us using existing BSP? What all modification have been done in romInit.s, romInit.s module performs the minimal preliminary board initialization and then jumps to the C routine romStart( ). Add some logging in romStart to see if you see that in console? As usrRoot function does all console related initialization, my suspect would be that we are not reaching that point. So try to find out whether we can get to romStart C routine or not.

Comment: Vikash, thanks for the hint. Is there a private email address I can reach you at?.

Comment: Vikash, my board has EFI (not BIOS). The board has a LED which can be toggled on and off by writing to an IO port register. I verified this @ EFI shell using mm command so I know it works. When I put this same code in RomStart() by calling sysInByte(), I do not see the LED getting toggled. I am not sure if bootrom is even meant to be used in EFI shell environment. Do you have any ideas on this?

Comment: i have never used EFI shell, can you point me which BSP your using and vxworks version?.  LED test is good start.

Comment: Vikash, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I am using the pcPentium4 BSP. I can use the one already provided or I can just build it from the Tornado GUI (or make bootrom from the target\proj\config\pcPentium4)

Comment: I see that romInit is calling romStart but I am not sure if the romStart is where I think it is defined. I intentionally introduced some compiler errors in romStart (all 3 versions) and recompiled bootrom and I do not see any compiler errors or warnings. Can you tell me how you test your bootrom?. My development host is in a VM in VMWare (XP 32-bit running in VMWare VM). After I build the bootrom, I map a virtual floppy image to the VM and do a mkboot a: bootrom. Then I copy the floppy image to a USB drive and boot from the USB disk

Comment: Use http://www.vxdev.com/down/appnote/appnote237.pdf to understand the   bootrom image part. I work on embedded, so we directly flash bootrom into flash using JTGAG debugger. Also refre vxworks BSP manual, that will help to debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. I have been able to load vxworks image. The problem now is that the kernelInit() function in usrConfig.c does not start the new task. I know the vxworks image is getting loaded because I have a reset function (by writing to port 0xcf9) and if I call that before kernelInit() the board resets. But the usrRoot() in usrConfig.c never starts.  There was a suspicion that interrupts might be enabled going into loading the vxworks image (from bootConfig.c). I am using PIC mode (just 8259 is enabled). Before kernelInit, EFLAGS:IF is 0 and PIC is disabled.